# PgAdmin4 keeps returning: ERROR: syntax error at or near "IN"

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query that updates all records inside my table and the values inside of each column should be in sync with my other table so i created this query:

```
UPDATE dashboard.event SET operation_start_time IN 
(SELECT operation_start FROM dashboard.inventory), operation_end_time IN 
(SELECT operation_end FROM dashboard.inventory) 
WHERE terminal_id IN (SELECT terminal_id FROM dashboard.inventory)
```

but the problem postgres keep returning me "ERROR:  syntax error at or near "IN"" in which i don't get why. If i put "=" instead of "IN" it returns me the error:

ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

For the logic of these query. I have an inventory table and in it has a column name operation_start and operation_end. I want the data in those columns to be updated or inserted in the event table for each terminal_id

Any help will be appreciated please. Thank you!

Comment: Please tell us what the logic of this update is.

Comment: `set column IN (...)` is invalid SQL to begin with.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update the columns in `event` from `inventory` for a given `terminal_id`, the the syntax would look like:

```
UPDATE dashboard.event e
    SET operation_start_time = e.operation_start,
        operation_end_time = e.operation_end
    FROM dashboard.inventory i
    WHERE e.terminal_id = i.terminal_id;
```